# How do I know which File Systems my linux supports?

Tags: linux, filesystems, kernel

I am working with linux 3.19.0+ and I want to know if my linux kernel supports f2fs (Flash-Friendly File System). How do I know that?

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general OS tech support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cat /proc/filesystems` should do the trick...